# Editing perforce files in gvim

Tags: vim, perforce

Is it possible to execute the command `p4 edit` on a file before saving it in gvim ?
and only if it is in a perforce work area ?

Answer (score 0):

You can hook into buffer writes with an `:autocmd BufWritePre *`.

To execute a system command via the shell, you can either use `:call system(...)` or `:! ...`; the later allows for interactivity (e.g. answering a prompt), but pops up a separate command window on Windows. If the p4 command is non-interactive, I'd suggest this:

```
:autocmd BufWritePre * call system('p4 edit ' . shellescape(expand('<afile>')))
```

To limit the autocmd to Perforce files, you can restrict the global `*` pattern with something more specific; cp. `:help autocmd-patterns`.

Or, you can define buffer-local `<buffer>` autocmds with the help of a [localrc plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3393); i.e. you place a `.lvimrc` file in the root directory of each Perforce repository.